# lag during scrolling in android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, lag

I have a listview in which I have to load different objects with text and standard image;but in the arraylist that I give to the listview there are some objects that have to be load with a different "row.xml". I don't know if I'm explained, probably the code will clarify all:

this is my adapter

```
    /**
 * 
 */


import java.util.List;

import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;



import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EventEntry> {

    Typeface face;
    private static final Integer LIST_HEADER = 0;
    private static final Integer LIST_ITEM = 2;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<EventEntry> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/arial.ttf");

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getViewOptimize(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getViewOptimize(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //piece of code for header items
        String headerText = getHeader(position);
        if(headerText != null) {

            View item = convertView;
            if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() != LIST_HEADER) {

                item = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.event_list_header, parent, false);
                item.setTag(LIST_HEADER);

            }

            TextView headerTextView = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lv_list_hdr);
            headerTextView.setText(headerText);
            return item;
        }



        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_event, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.first = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ev_tit_list);
            viewHolder.second = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ev_image_list);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            try{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }catch(ClassCastException e){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_event, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.first = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ev_tit_list);
                viewHolder.second = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ev_image_list);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
        }
        EventEntry e = getItem(position);
        if (e.getEvento()!=null)
            return setEventItem(viewHolder, e.getEvento(), convertView);
        else 
            return setSagraItem(viewHolder, e.getSagra(), convertView);


    }

    public View setEventItem(ViewHolder viewHolder, Entry2ev e, View convertView){

        viewHolder.first.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD );
        viewHolder.first.setText(e.getTit());
        viewHolder.second.setImageResource(e.getIm());

        SVG svg_event = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getContext().getResources(), R.raw.eventi_principale);
        viewHolder.second.setImageDrawable(svg_event.createPictureDrawable());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            viewHolder.second.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public View setSagraItem(ViewHolder viewHolder, EntrySagreEvent e, View convertView){

        viewHolder.first.setText(e.getName());
        viewHolder.first.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD );

        viewHolder.second.setImageResource(R.drawable.shop);

        return convertView;
    }

      private String getHeader(int position) {

          if(getItem(position).getMonth()!=null) {
              return getItem(position).getMonth();
          }
          else
              return null;
      }


    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView first;
        public ImageView second;
    }
}
```

what can i do to get a laggy-free scroll? thank you very much

Comment: Generally when you want to show more than one "type" of row view you would implement `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount`, and then switch over the return value of `getItemViewType` inside of `getView`. I'm not actually sure that will do much here, it seems like you use the same layout resource in both cases. What **does** stand out to me is the `SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(...)`. How expensive is that call? Do you need to parse this resource on every call to `getView`, or can you do it once during construction and cache the result?

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips! I'll look at getItemViewType in order to see if there is something better to do in my code; I totally forgot the call to SVGParser! I deleted it for testing, it's unnecessary!

Answer (score 2):

You want to reference this article by Google:  http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Particularly, you should be using a ViewHolder, so the items are created only once and then re-used.  You'll see performance greatly improve.

Comment: Thank you, but I've alrealdy used Holder pattern

Answer (score 0):

Dont initialise that Typephase in custom adapter, instead of that pass it as an argument from the previous class. Problem solved for me doing same.